# Evaluating key values in multi-dimensional object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a multi-dimensional object that looks like this:

```
{
 "links": [{"source":"58","target":"john","total":"95"},
           {"source":"60","target":"mark","total":"80"}],
 "nodes": 
          [{"name":"john"}, {"name":"mark"}, {"name":"rose"}]
}
```

I am trying to evaluate the value of "total" in "links." I can do this in a one-dimensional array, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data[i]) {
        if (!isNaN(data[i][key])) {
            data[i][key] = +data[i][key];
        }
    }
};
```

But I have not been able to figure out how to do this in two-dimensions (especially calling the value of key "total" by name).

Can anybody set me on the right track?  Thank you!

Comment: does this code above work for your one-dim array? how are you only adding up 'total' numbers instead of anything that's just a number?

Comment: In my one-dim array I check each key to see if it looks like a number and if it does, it's converted to a number. The "+" before the data item converts in in d3.js.  I'm really just interested in learning how to get down to the key called "total" in my multi-dim array, using similar loop logic that I typed above.

Comment: You have two, one dimensional array. Perform the same kind of thing that you would do on a normal array, just at `data.links` and `data.nodes`.

Comment: This question is not about JSON. Read the usage description of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the principle that the structure of your array is this, you can to iterate the keys and the values:

```js
var obj = {
 "links": [{"source":"58","target":"john","total":"95"},
           {"source":"60","target":"mark","total":"80"}],
 "nodes": 
          [{"name":"john"}, {"name":"mark"}, {"name":"rose"}]
};

for (var key in obj){
  obj[key].forEach(function(item){
    for(var subkey in item){
      if (subkey == 'total')
        console.log(item[subkey]);
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much, this is a big help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get total using reduce

check this snippet

```js
var obj = {
  "links": [{
    "source": "58",
    "target": "john",
    "total": "95"
  }, {
    "source": "60",
    "target": "mark",
    "total": "80"
  }, {
    "source": "60",
    "target": "mark",
    "total": "80"
  }],
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "john"
  }, {
    "name": "mark"
  }, {
    "name": "rose"
  }]
}

var links = obj.links;
var sum = links.map(el => el.total).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return parseInt(prev, 10) + parseInt(curr, 10);

});
console.log(sum);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Extract the values from the array, convert them to numbers and add them up.**

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) are pretty helpful here:

```js
var data = {"links":[{"source":"58","target":"john","total":"95"},{"source":"60","target":"mark","total":"80"}], "nodes":[{"name":"john"}, {"name":"mark"}, {"name":"rose"}]};

var sum = data.links.map(function(link) {
  return +link.total;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});

console.log(sum);
```